# Clear stack of activities OnBackpressed ()

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to  clear stack of activities onBackpresed on the mainactivity

i know i have to use

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

but the problem is the intent also 
 i found this code

```
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(startMain);
```

But it forces the device  to go to the home screen

Comment: so u want to exit after back press from main activity?

Comment: yes and also clear stack of activities

Comment: did u tried inten.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: use add flags instead of setfalgs

Comment: the problem is in the intent itself where is the activity i have to move to 
i don't want to open activity 
Intent i=new Intent(Main.this,settings.class);

Comment: startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); should make u go to home screen of device isnt it?

Comment: yes but it forces the device to do this i want to return the screen 
that is foucesed by the user

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34387/discussion-between-stacks28-and-mrx10)

Answer (score -4):

you can code

> System.exit(0)

when exit application
System.exit(0) can shutdown JVM,and system will clear stack by GC；